# Can I have my derived class automatically use the base constructor?

Tags: vb.net, constructor, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that has two constructors.  When another class inherits this class, it appears that I have to declare contructors with identical signatures as the ones in the base class.  This seems a bit redundant to me.  Is there a way to have `Sub New(Parameter as MyClass)` in my base class and have this become the default constructor signature unless the derived class includes it in its definition?

**Edit for clarity**:  I was hoping it was implied that I do not want to have to create a constructor in the derived class that calls the base class.  I would like to be able to do this:

```
Mustinherit Class MyBase

  Sub New(MyParam As String)

  End Sub

End Class

Class MyDerived
  Inherits MyBase

End Class
```

Notice now the derived class doesn't call the base?

Comment: Just saw your edit. You can't do that; suppose the base class had some state which is initialized from the constructor parameters. When creating a derived class object, how can the compiler know how to initialize the state inherited from the base class if you don't call the base constructor? Like @PhonicUK said, if your abstract class has no state (no fields), it would be better off as an interface.

Comment: To clarify the question: this isn't asking whether base constructor can avoid being called, it is asking whether that call can be *implicit* - not have to write the code that simply calls through to the base. IMHO, while having to do so is occasionally inconvenient, it is good that the compiler not attempt to automatically generate this code:  if this syntax were allowed, someone reading text of `MyDerived` would not know what constructor(s) exist - they would have to look in base. Also, if a second constructor is added to `MyBase`, there is no control over which are allowed in `MyDerived`.

Comment: ... this is an example of a *code editing convenience* - it could be "fixed" by adding an option to *a smart text editor* (that keeps a live analysis of your solution's existing classes): When you create a subclass, it suggests constructors that call through to the base constructors.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In VB.Net you use:

`MyBase.New(args)`

Inside your constructors method body, no extra verbiage is used on the constructors/method signature.

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example.  It seems your answer confirmed that I cannot do this, but perhaps there is a way to get it to work using syntax I am not familiar with.

Comment: Updated my answer. I suspect you don't actually want to be using an abstract class for this, but rather an interface.

Comment: PLEASE update your answer to actually answer the question. this should be VB, not C#

Comment: @PhonicUK I would upvote your answer, but having an accepted answer with a -7 vote is a feat deserving a badge. :D :D :D

Answer (score 34):

Your assumption is wrong; your derived classes' constructors can have any signature, as long as they call one of their base class's constructor properly using MyBase.New. Here's a full example:

```
Imports System

Public Class MainClass

    Shared Sub Main()
         Dim w As New Window(5, 10)
         w.DrawWindow(  )

         Dim lb As New ListBox(20, 30, "Hello world")
         lb.DrawWindow(  )

    End Sub
End Class

 Public Class Window
     Public Sub New(ByVal top As Integer, ByVal left As Integer)
         Me.top = top
         Me.left = left
     End Sub 'New

     Public Sub DrawWindow(  )
         Console.WriteLine("Drawing Window at {0}, {1}", top, left)
     End Sub

     Private top As Integer
     Private left As Integer

 End Class

 Public Class ListBox
     Inherits Window

     Public Sub New(ByVal top As Integer, ByVal left As Integer, ByVal theContents As String)
         MyBase.New(top, left) ' 
         mListBoxContents = theContents
     End Sub 

     Public Shadows Sub DrawWindow(  )
         MyBase.DrawWindow(  ) 
         Console.WriteLine("Writing string to the listbox: {0}", mListBoxContents)
     End Sub 

     Private mListBoxContents As String 

 End Class
```

**EDIT**: You are not forced to keep or extend the base class constructor's signature at all. This is valid, for example:

```
Public Class ListBox
     Inherits Window

     Public Sub New(ByVal theContents As String)
         MyBase.New(20, 30) ' 
         mListBoxContents = theContents
     End Sub 

     'More code

 End Class
```